# How to check if a row exists in SQL, by index OR by value?

Tags: sql, null

Assume that I have a table of cables with the following columns:

```
id, type_id, is_working, box_id, cable_length
```

If I want to check if `box_id` exists in the table, how can I do it?

Should I check if the index in the table equals to NULL or should I check if the value on the column equals to NULL?

If any clarification is needed, I will be glad to clarify the question.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Where do you want to 'check it exists' ?  In a query? In a subquery? as part of an if statement? etc, etc, What have you tried?

Comment: You would do something like: Select * from myTable where box_id is not null. If you are checking for a specific id then: Select * from myTable where box_id = < desiredId >

Comment: Thanks both of you for replying.  My goal is to search for a row in the table, but before I find it and does something with it, I want to know whether it is NULL. How should I check it, by the index in the table, or by the value of the row?

Comment: your question is not clear. Consider adding some sample data and desired results. Help us help you and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). also, 
as the *sql tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to know if there are any rows in the table of cables with specific `box_id` value, is that correct?

If so, you can check it in few different ways with different results of the query.

1. You can find all rows with specific `box_id`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cables WHERE box_id = 3
```

This gives you all rows with `box_id` = 3. (Possibly none.)

2. You can check the count of the rows with specific `box_id`.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cables WHERE box_id = 3
```

This gives you the number of rows with `box_id` = 3. If none found, returns 0, not nothing.

3. You can check if any row with specific `box_id` exists.

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END FROM cables WHERE box_id = 3
```

This returns true, if any row with `box_id` = 3 exists, otherwise returns false.
However, I tried this query only on PostgreSQL database and am not sure whether it is a valid query on other types of databases or not.

It is up to you which approach you may prefer. To me, the first one is pretty much suitable and most straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, you misunderstood my question. My goal is to search for a row in the table, but before I find it, I want to know whether it is NULL. How should I check it, by the index in the table, or by the value of the row?